# Delivery radius for a restaurant in Apple Maps

Tags: ios, geometry, mapkit

I'm trying to develop a delivery system for a restaurant, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem. The restaurant has five locations; four of them are in one state and the other is in a different state.

They only do deliveries for each location depending on how far it is; they also have setup certain limitations for each location.

My idea will be:

- Fetch user's location on iOS (Accomplished)
- Check if user location is inside of any Restaurant delivery radius. If so, set that location as the store, if not, just show a message that we don't delivery in their area.

Where I'm stuck

- How can I define in Apple Maps the limits of Location 1, 2, 3, etc. (meaning what area will they be doing delivery to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the deliverable radius around the location of the restaurant. You can even draw an MKCircle to be fancy.

```
CLLocation * _storeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:30.270135 longitude:-97.731270];

double deliverableRadius = 3 * 1609.34; // 3 miles (or the area they will deliver to)

MKCircle * circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:storeLocation.coordinate radius:deliverableRadius];
[_mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

Once you have established the deliverable area, you can check to see if the see if the users location is within this area.

Comment: Is a circle the only solution?

Comment: No, but it at least shows the user the delivery area. The point being, is you can still use the `deliverableRadius ` to determine if the user is within that "circle".

Answer (score 0):

So I think a simple approach might be to simply check if the user is within a certain distance of a restaurant (ie "If I am less than 25 miles from a restaurant, then they will deliver to me").

First convert the address of the restaurant locations into gps coordinates. See [Converting Place Names Into Coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html) for more info.

Next, calculate the distance between the user's location and the location of each restaurant and check if that distance less than the maximum delivery distance.

A formula for calcualating the distance between two points can be found [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm).